# How to consume a ASP.NET Core WebAPI in a C# UWP application?

Tags: rest, wcf, asp.net-core, uwp

I am trying to understand how it is possible to consume a ASP.NET Core WebAPI within an UWP/UAP application.
I thought I would be possible to consume the WebAPI similar to consuming a WCF Service but I haven't found anything about that yet.

Furthermore I tried to install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core but had no success as it is not compatible with UAP (Version=V10.0).

I am a bit lost now. Maybe someone could give me a hint how I could use the WebApi within the UWP application.

Comment: ASP.NET Core WebAPI is not like WCF. That it is it does not provide any standard ways to consume it like WCF does, there is no automatically generated client for consuming of WebAPI endpoints. 
ASP.NET uses HTTP as protocol, so you can use WebClient or something similar to send HTTP requests and the parse responses from JSON or XML to objects and do you business logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the same as consuming any API call. Simply use the `HttpClient` class to invoke the endpoint and handle the response, there is no difference in the expected behaviour.

Imagine that you have an **ASP.NET Core Web API** endpoint defined like this:

```
public class StackoverflowController : Controller
{    
    // I wanted to exemplify async capabilities.
    // You'd use async/await for getting database values, etc.
    [
        HttpGet,
        AllowAnonymous,
        Route("api/greeting")
    ]
    public Task<GreetingResult> Greeting() =>
        Task.FromResult(new GreetingResult { Message = "Hello world!" });
}

public class GreetingResult
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming this was hosted on `localhost:5000' you could do the following:

```
public class Consumer
{
    public async Task<string> GetGreetingAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = 
                await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5000/api/greeting");
            // The response object is a string that looks like this:
            // "{ message: 'Hello world!' }"
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, you could deserialize this as a strongly typed object use `Newtonsoft.Json`. I have an example of my UWP app doing this very thing [here](https://github.com/IEvangelist/Mirror/blob/master/Mirror/Networking/ApiClient.cs).

Comment: thank you very much. That is the explanation I needed. Yesterday I already found an explanation how to do it in UWP and I think my biggest problem was, not to know that there is this HttpClient class available in WinRT. I thought I had to reference ASP.NET Core to my UWP application somehow.

Comment: I've a little off topic question to the following code snippet: **public Task<GreetingResult> Greeting() => Task.FromResult(new GreetingResult { Message = "Hello world!" });**. I never saw this kind of assigning a Task to a delegate (?). What is this Greeting()? Excuse this stupid question.

Comment: @Chris I'm hoping that you'll upvote and accept answers. `Greeting()` is a method, this is C# 6 syntax where simple members can be defined as expressions using the `goes to` operator, i.e.; `=>`.

Answer (score 5):

I will add some more information to that:

Best way to consume Web Api in UWP is to use HttpClient as mentioned before.

Here are some examples I think might be helpful.

The good practice is to create MobileServiceClient class where you can collect all operations that you can perform on the Web Api level:

```
public class MobileServiceClient
{
    //access token if you use authentication:
    private string _accessToken;
    //address of your Web Api:
    private string _serviceAddress;

    //Constructor:
    public MobileServiceClient(string accessToken, string serviceAddress)
    {
        _accessToken = accessToken;
        _serviceAddress = serviceAddress;
    }

//Now you can implement methods that you will invoke to perform selected operation related with Web Api:

#region Methods

//You can perform "Get" to retrieve object from the Web Api and then deserialize it (using Json .NET):

public async Task<SampleClass> GetSampleClass()
    {
        SampleClass sampleClass= null;
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);
                var data = await client.GetAsync(string.Concat(_serviceAddress, "routeName"));
                var jsonResponse = await data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (jsonResponse != null)
                    sampleClass= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleClass>(jsonResponse);
                return sampleClass;
            }
        }

        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            throw new WebException("An error has occurred while calling GetSampleClass method: " + exception.Message);
        }
    }

//You can perform "Get" to retrieve list of objects and then deserialize it:

public async Task<List<SampleClass>> GetSampleClassObjects()
    {
        List<SampleClass> SampleClassObjectsList = null;
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);
                var data = await client.GetAsync(string.Concat(_serviceAddress, "routeName"));
                var jsonResponse = await data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (jsonResponse != null)
                    SampleClassObjectsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SampleClass>>(jsonResponse);
                return SampleClassObjectsList;
            }
        }

        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            throw new WebException("An error has occurred while calling GetSampleClassObjects method: " + exception.Message);
        }
    }

//You can also "Post" some object:

public async Task<bool> PostSomeObject(SampleClass sampleClassObject)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var sampleClassObjectJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sampleClassObject);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);
                var content = new StringContent(sampleClassObjectJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(string.Concat(_serviceAddress + "routeName"), content);
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    return true;
                else
                    throw new WebException("An error has occurred while calling PostSomeObject method: " + response.Content);
            }
        }

        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            throw new WebException("An error has occurred while calling PostFeedback method: " + exception.Message);
        }
    }
#endregion
}
```

Please note that with such implementation you can share the code in the future if you decide for instance to support other platfroms (like Xamarin Android or iOS).
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Where does JsonConvert come frome?

Comment: Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET: https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/ (for UWP too).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure Newtonsoft.Json was ready for Core yet.

Answer (score 3):

David Pines answer is good enough if you want to do all the stuff manually and/or you don't use swagger.

If you use Swagger (i.e. [Swashbuckle Swagger 6.0](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Ahoy) for ASP.NET Core) to describe your RESTful API and generate documentation for it, you can use the swagger definition file (swagger.json) to generate an Rest Client. One such tool is [AutoRest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest), created by the Azure team. It will also require [Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime/) which already supports DotNet.

I'm not sure if it runs with ASP.NET Core RTM yet, but there were solved/closed issues indicating that it had support for previous versions and betas merged into it.

NuGet Package Links

- [AutoRest](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoRest/)
- [Client Runtime for Microsoft AutoRest Generated Clients](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime/)